# Issue Constructing SQLAlchemy Query

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a list of `id`s that correspond to requests by a client.

I have 2 tables of interest:

```
**Request**
id
time_of_creation
```

and

```
**Reply**
id
request_id (foreign key to `id` in request)
timestamp
```

Each request can have multiple replies. I want a list of all the time differences between each request and it earliest reply.

Currently, I do

```
reply_table = aliased(Reply, name='ReplyTable')
request_table = aliased(Request, name='RequestTable')
s = (cls.session.query(func.min(reply_table.timestamp).label('timestamp')).
         join(request_table).
         filter(request_table.id.in_(requests)))
query = (cls.session.query(Reply.timestamp, Request.time_of_creation).
             filter(
               Reply.timestamp.in_(s),
               Request.id.in_(requests)
              ).join(Request))
return query.all()
```

where `requests` might look something like `[1, 100, 200, .. 3]`.

Unfortunately, only one value is returned by this result. Is this the correct way to nest 2 queries to return a list of `timestamp` and `time_of_creation` pairs so that I can take the time difference of each pair in the resultant list?

Answer (score 0):

You get only one result because you are missing a `group_by` in your `s` subquery, thus you are getting the global minimum. It should be something like,

```
s = (session.query(func.min(Reply.timestamp).label('timestamp'))
        .join(Request)
        .filter(Request.id.in_(requests))
        .group_by(Request.id))
```

(I haven't used aliases in my trials.)

Hope it helps.